# Apply Logic In a MySQL Column with IF or Case

Tags: mysql, if-statement, subquery, left-join, mysql-5.6

I face this problem and I can't think of a way to proceed. So, I have a table let's say with 3 entries with the same id and a column named `status` that has for the first entry the value `active`, for the second entry the value `inactive` and `paused` for the last. Keep in mind that the logic should be applied in a join since the query that already runs is quite big.

So I a want to create a subquery to say if there is at least one status `active` return status `active` for this id, if there is no status `active` but there is one status `paused` return status `paused`, otherwise return status`inactive`.

I tried already to use `IF()` with `group_concat()` for all the statuses and also a `CASE` statement but I don't get the required result.

Any guess on that? P.S: I am using MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
         THEN 'active'
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'paused' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
         THEN 'paused'
         ELSE 'inactive' END AS status
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I see now! Didn't know that you can get this result by using the sum of another nested case. Really useful approach thanks Tim :)